# How to change a phpspreadsheet-object into a html-object

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I'm working with phpspreadsheet. In a part of my code I have to generate a html-object:

```
$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Html($spreadsheet);
$writer->save($fileNameHTML);
$html = file_get_contents($fileNameHTML);
```

I need a function without save and load the html file. Maybe something like "$html = $spreadsheet" (not working ;-))

Answer (score 0):

and here is my answer:

```
$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Html($spreadsheet);
ob_start();
$writer->save('php://output');
$html = ob_get_clean();
```

My misstake: $html is not an object. It's a string.